# DataNucleus many-many attributed relation. Relation object deleted after removal from related objects

Tags: java, jdo, datanucleus

Based on this sample here, https://github.com/datanucleus/samples-jdo/blob/master/many_to_many_attributed/src/main/java/org/datanucleus/samples/jdo/many_many_attributed2/Main.java, I created CompanyProduct relation with the following codes.

Company.java

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, cacheable = "false", detachable = "true")
public class Company implements Serializable {
...
@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
long id;
@Persistent
private String name = null;
@Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true", mappedBy = "company")
private Set<CompanyProduct> companyProduct = new HashSet<>(); 
...
}
```

Product.java

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, cacheable = "false", detachable = "true")
public class Product implements Serializable {
...
@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
long id;
@Persistent
private String name = null;
@Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true", mappedBy = "product")
private Set<CompanyProduct> companyProduct = new HashSet<>(); 
...
}
```

CompanyProduct.java

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, cacheable = "false", detachable = "true")
public class CompanyProduct implements Serializable {
...
@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
long id;
@Persistent
private String name = null;
@Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
private Company company;
@Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
private Product product; 
...
}
```

Main.java

```
...
tx.begin();
CompanyProduct companyProduct = new CompanyProduct();
Company company = pm.getObjectById(Company.class, companyId);
Product product= pm.getObjectById(Product.class, productId);

companyProduct.setCompany(company);
companyProduct.setProduct(product);

company.addCompanyProduct(companyProduct);
product.addCompanyProduct(companyProduct);

pm.makePersistent(companyProduct);
tx.commit();

...
```

Removing the relation

```
tx.begin();
CompanyProduct comProd= pm.getObjectById(CompanyProduct.class, companyProduct.getId());

comProd.removeCompanyProduct(comProd);
comProd.removeCompanyProduct(comProd);

pm.makePersistent(comProd);
tx.commit();
```

Removing the relation object from the relating objects, automatically deletes the relation object after commit. I could not access it again if I want to re-add it to the relating objects.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm not sure about the specific implementation, but a relation object does not conceptually exist except in the context of the two other objects it connects.  If you detach it from one or both of its objects, it ceases to have any meaning and a well-designed ORM would be justified in deleting it, otherwise you leave useless cruft in the database.  If you need to recreate it you'll have to save the relationship object's state (its internal values pertaining to the relationship itself) and recreate it when needed.

Comment: Clearly JDO defines semantics when you delete things, or remove objects from relations to prevent orphans. You have a LOG that tells you what happens in terms of database communication; you don't seem to be looking at that ...

Comment: Thanks, @Jim @DN1. I have been thinking about this automatic deletion. When a partner of a relationship withdraws, the relationship will cease to exist. This is a common sense, that is why its deletion is justified. But the issue of application Identity, when the object is deleted the key ``id`` will not be used again by the Application. Is there anything like exhausting the key number allocation?

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve this problem of automatic deletion by adding and setting **dependent** and **dependent-element** attributes to false. I updated my code as follows;

Company.java

```
...
@Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true", mappedBy = "company", dependentElement = "false")
private Set<CompanyProduct> companyProduct = new HashSet<>(); 
...
```

Product.java

```
@Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true", mappedBy = "product", dependentElement = "false")
private Set<CompanyProduct> companyProduct = new HashSet<>();
```

CompanyProduct.java

```
...
@Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true", dependent = "false")
private Company company;
@Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true", dependent = "false")
private Product product; 
...
```

Comment: No. You were advised that JDO has defined semantics for what happens when you remove relations. You haven't checked/defined how those apply in your case. That is what a LOG shows

Comment: Could you please give me a link on this, so that I can update my knowledge. I do not know how and what to define here, if not to remove the relation from the relating objects like ``cust1.removeRelation(rel);``. Thanks.

Comment: I would have thought the docs for the JDO provider is where to start. Delete dependent and other such options, and the LOG of course, but already mentioned that ...

Comment: @DN1. Yes. I have got it by adding and setting ``dependent`` and ``dependent-element`` to ``false``. But there is an issue here, the fields value on the related objects on the relation object  are null. For me to identify this particular relation object there is a need to add a second id or key derived from the relating objects id like a compound id, since I am using Application Identity. What do you think?

Comment: No idea what you are talking about. Suggest that you REWRITE your question with code, and what is "null"